# How to search in a select option by text in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, select

I have a visible and a hidden select option. When user selects something, I want to get the selected option and search text in hidden select option. Because I need the val of hidden select option that matches with the selected text. First I tried;

```
var testx=document.getElementById("priceMatrix");
testx.options[testx.selectedIndex].text=toAdd+"|"+cupSize;
```

it works, I can set text but still can not set the value. and I tried secondly;

```
    var myText = toAdd+"|"+cupSize;
    $('#priceMatrix').filter(function () { return $(this).html() == myText; }).prop('selected', true)
    var alertText = $("#priceMatrix option:selected").val();
    alert(alertText);
```

but still it does not work, $("#priceMatrix option:selected").val(); gives the first row's value, not the selected one.

So, what is the problem? is it about button click?

Comment: Can you give us more information? Some HTML and any other javascript you're running would be extremely helpful to providing you with correct code.

Comment: I have two select in my html, #priceMatrix is hidden one and #chooseItem is visible one. Both of them has same text but hidden one have different values. When user choose "abc" from #chooseItem, I want to change the hidden one's text to "abc" and get the value of the "abc". I tried also change event but it still doesnt work.

Comment: An additional line to the first snippet: `testx.options[testx.selectedIndex].value=toAdd+"|"+cupSize;`.

Comment: the value is different in the second select, so I can't set it like that. I need the second select's value that match the text selected above.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution and Want to share it. I made a for loop to go into the select. when I find the matching text, I set it selected then I get the value.

```
    var selectedOption = toAdd+"|"+cupSize;
    var selectLength = document.getElementById("priceMatrix").length;
    var priceMatrix = document.getElementById("priceMatrix");

    for(i=0; i<selectLength;i++){
        if (priceMatrix[i].text === selectedOption) {
            priceMatrix[i].selected = 'selected';
            var price = $("#priceMatrix option:selected").val();
            var totalPrice = itemNbr1*price;
        }

    }
    alert(totalPrice);
```